# Multiple install for multilanguage. How to?

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I (will) have a multilingual (3 lang actually) site.

I used WMPL some time, but this plugine made me sad...

Finally, I decided to install each language a part.

How should it be done? I have my `/`
So, should I install
`/en` `/fr` `/it` or
`/` + `/fr` `/it`

is there some plugin that will help me to synchronize content?

Comment: Have you tried qTranslate?
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for /en/ in order to prevent future issues and keep isolated the content that is not localizable. From my knowledge WPML does not support this yet.

Comment: so, what happen with the root folder?

Comment: when I open myexample.com I will need to redirect it to, say, "/it" in a way by default

Comment: could you take a look http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3479/multisite-how-to-remove-the-root-site

Answer (score 1):

Are you ready to use WordPress network ? If yes, the new release of xili-language premium can answer to your question. It is working well and is yet dedicaced to pro webmasters.

Comment: Borderline spam.  Could you edit to not sound so much like a infomercial?

Comment: As developer of free plugins, I think it can be useful to inform that we are working on a new release or that a future version is yet working on websites. It is also a way to be informed that the subject is interesting for others. a [link](http://dev.xiligroup.com/?p=2109)

Comment: Last post about the xili-language on 2013... User only answered this and was never seen again... posted useful answers with self-promotion (editing now)