# Multisite - how to remove the root '/' site?

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I want to install WP in 3 languages: en, ro, ru

```
mysite.com/en
mysite.com/ro
mysite.com/ru
```

I was not sure, but installed WP in the root folder.

Now I need to redirect visitors to default language. Say "en".
AND I don't need having 4 sites actually: `/`, `/en/`, `/ro/`, `/ru/`, but 3.

The situation is actually like this

[image]

I can't "remove" the "/" site, actually

Comment: Do you really want different websites for each language? Why dont you use WPML plugin instead?

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea WPML plugin is a plugin with bugs. And it does not translates the images on themes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use on the root site a small theme for redirect to the languages. A very small theme for locate the language of the users and redirect to the blog of this language.

```
<?php
// Browsersprache ermitteln
function lang_get_from_browser($allowed_languages, $default_language, $lang_variable = NULL, $strict_mode = TRUE) {
    // $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] verwenden, wenn keine Sprachvariable mitgegeben wurde
    if ( NULL === $lang_variable )
        $lang_variable = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

    // wurde irgendwelche Information mitgeschickt?
    if ( empty($lang_variable) ) 
        return $default_language;

    // Den Header auftrennen
    $accepted_languages = preg_split('/,\s*/', $lang_variable);

    // Die Standardwerte einstellen
    $current_lang = $default_language;
    $current_q    = 0;
    // Nun alle mitgegebenen Sprachen abarbeiten
    foreach ($accepted_languages as $accepted_language) {
        // Alle Infos dieser Sprache rausholen
        $res = preg_match(
            '/^([a-z]{1,8}(?:-[a-z]{1,8})*)'.
            '(?:;\s*q=(0(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?|1(?:\.0{1,3})?))?$/i', 
            $accepted_language, 
            $matches
        );

        if (!$res)
            continue;

        // Sprachcode holen und dann sofort in die Einzelteile trennen
        $lang_code = explode('-', $matches[1]);

        // Wurde eine Qualität mitgegeben?
        if ( isset($matches[2]) )
            $lang_quality = (float)$matches[2];
        else
            $lang_quality = 1.0;

        // Bis der Sprachcode leer ist...
        while (count ($lang_code)) {
            // mal sehen, ob der Sprachcode angeboten wird
            if (in_array ( strtolower( join('-', $lang_code) ), $allowed_languages) ) {
                // Qualität anschauen
                if ($lang_quality > $current_q) {
                    $current_lang = strtolower( join('-', $lang_code) );
                    $current_q = $lang_quality;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Wenn wir im strengen Modus sind, die Sprache nicht versuchen zu minimalisieren
            if ($strict_mode)
                break;

            // den rechtesten Teil des Sprachcodes abschneiden
            array_pop($lang_code);
        }
    }

    return $current_lang;
}

$allowed_langs = array('en', 'de');
$lang = lang_get_from_browser($allowed_langs, 'en', NULL, FALSE);

if ( 'de' === $lang )
    Header("Location: http://wpbasis.de/readme-de_DE.php");
else
    Header("Location: http://wpbasis.de/readme-en_US.php");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you be so kind to translate your comments to English? I don't need them but I don't want to include non-English comments in any of the files, it not good for maintenance. Also the solution could be adapted to use the languages defined in WordPress instead of harcoding them.

Comment: I will write my code in a theme for free, then its all in english.

Comment: yeah. English comments rulles. Even If I am not a native English Speaker, I try to comment in English my code :)
But, I don't understand, why this code you name "theme". Where should I find such a theme?

Comment: i create a theme for WordPress in root blog for rewrite, current i write a theme for this.

Comment: I didn't get it... Where do I need to put this code above?

Comment: @bueltge: To stay with the comment language: Na das ist ja einmal gewaltig geil!

Comment: @rgcf: this is only a fragment, use it in a theme of the root blog or create a plugin and activate. I think the easiest way is to use in a theme.

Comment: @kaiser: sorry, die Zeit :(

Comment: @bueltge: Damit hab ich eigentlich die Funktion/Plugin gemeint. Ist wirklich eine geile Lösung :)

Comment: @kaiser: yes, we work on a plugin for also this feature in a multisite install and lot of more to use WP MU for Multilanguage blogs; example: dashbaord widget with all posts fomr all blogs and links to the post, to xopy in other blogs etc....

Answer (score 2):

just leave it and place a redirect on it?